# Adding objects to a Set in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, set

I am not sure if there is a set data structure in JS like in python. I have an array of objects like this in Javascript, the ID is unique. If I have two arrays like this - how can I combine them into a single array where I throw away duplicates based on the ID field?

First array:

[{
     filed : "1-Jan-1970",
     name: "John Smith",
     ID: 1234
    }
    ... (many more items)
    ]

Second array:

[{
     filed : "1-Jan-1980",
     name: "John Smith",
     ID: 1234
    }
    ... (many more items)
    ]

In the combined array I only want to keep one item with ID = 1234. I dont care which one is thrown away, how do I do this in Javascript that is also fast? I am looking at combining two lists with a couple of thousand items each and I want to keep only one record per ID from either array. Is there a compact way to combine the two arrays into one and then weed out the duplicates?

Comment: Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from ids to objects

Comment: yeah, ES6 gives Set data structure